# Terminal not recognizing updated User Defaults

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, terminal, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to alter the save location of screenshots from within an Mac OS application, however this doesn't seem to work.

Executing the following commands in the terminal works perfect. All screenshots are saved in a folder named *Screenshots* (located on my desktop), just as expected.

**Terminal**

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Desktop/Screenshots
killall SystemUIServer
```

Whenever I let my application execute the following snippet, the location value in `com.apple.screencapture.plist` will change just as its supposed to.

**Objective-C**

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"com.apple.screencapture.plist"];

[defaults setValue:@"/Users/Maarten/Desktop/Screenshots" forKey:@"location"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

After the value has changed, I use the terminal to run `killall SystemUIServer`

But somehow this command doesn't seem to work, as all screenshots are saved in its previous defined (*default*) location.

Comment: I've come up with this myself already. I've tried multiple intervals up to a minute. No changes whatsoever.

Comment: `defaults read com.apple.screencapture location` will result in the new location. Both before and after executing `killall SystemUIServer`.

Comment: Yes, it does exist. I noticed that a reboot will accept the changes, so I assume that there must be some other command (besides `killall SystemUIServer`) to process the new values.

Comment: A reboot should not be required. There are third-party utilities that can make this change instantaneously and without the need to reboot. The fact that you can use `defaults` and `killall` in Terminal and it works but not with the other method shows a reboot is not required. There is something else going one here and unfortunately I'm not sure what it is as I cannot test under the same conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since 10.9 (I think), the OS caches your preferences. To invalidate the cache, you need to kill `cfprefsd`. So, first, set your preference via `defaults` then run this command:

```
killall -u $USER cfprefsd
```

After that, your preference should take without needing a restart or anything else.

Also, you can use `screencapture` to specify the location for a specific screenshot instead of changing the system preference. You can specify other parameters using this tool as well. Use `man screencapture` for more information.

Finally, from Apple's documentation, `synchronize` is superflous for `NSUserDefaults`:

> **synchronize**
>
> Waits for any pending asynchronous updates to the defaults database
>   and returns; this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Very helpful, this did the job perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that this command will make executing `killAll SystemUIServer` obsolete. That's a nice extra.